# Android : transform ArrayList with a key

Tags: android, arraylist, key

I have a ArrayList that gives me datas like :

```
[0]
    {
        "prd_id": 65,
        "prd_img_mtime": 1543616875,
        "prd_img_md5": "f5ec4b6a1517c607953b55aa31bdf956"
    },
[1]
    {
        "prd_id": 72,
        "prd_img_mtime": 1543616815,
        "prd_img_md5": "4f49d80c48bff5ea5cfe329829e4e29e"
    }
```

And I have to find records with prd_id key.
So, I think I should transform this array to something like :

```
[65]
    {
        "prd_img_mtime": 1543616875,
        "prd_img_md5": "f5ec4b6a1517c607953b55aa31bdf956"
    },
[72]
    {
        "prd_img_mtime": 1543616815,
        "prd_img_md5": "4f49d80c48bff5ea5cfe329829e4e29e"
    }
```

then get record with myarray[index]
But how can I do this transformation please ?

Or, may be have you another solution, better.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you.

Make one class like this.

```
public class Details{
    long prd_id;
    String prd_img_mtime;
    String prd_img_md5;

       //getters here like getId , getTime, getMD5

}
```

Use getter to get the value.

Make ArrayList of type `Details`(Ex. ArrayList arrayList)

Now use for loop to get details.

```
for(Details details : arrayList){
    long id = details.getId;
    if(id==65){
         //use getters to get value and store it.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I finaly did :

```
Map<Integer, Product> prodsConverted = new HashMap<Integer, Product>();
for (Product prd : prods) {
    prodsConverted.put(prd.getId(),prd);
}
```

so now I can get my object with : prodsConverted.get(id)